# Creating List of OrderedDict from another list of OrderedDict

Tags: python

I have a list of `OrderedDict` that looks like this

```
OrderedDict([('Name', 'A'), ('Second_Name', 'D'),  ('Total', 294.3)])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'B'),  ('Second_Name', 'D'), ('Total', 294)])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'C'),  ('Second_Name', 'C'),  ('Total', 474)])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'D'),  ('Second_Name', 'A'),  ('Total', 374)])
```

I want to create another list of `OrderedDict` from this after applying a `function` and the expected output is like below

```
OrderedDict([('Name', 'A'),('B',custom_function(294.3,294)),('c',custom_function(294.3,474)),('D',custom_function(294.3,374))])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'B'),('A',custom_function(294,294.3)),('c',custom_function(294,474)),('D',custom_function(294,374))])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'C'),('A',custom_function(474,294.3)),('B',custom_function(474,294)),('D',custom_function(474,374))])
OrderedDict([('Name', 'D'),('A',custom_function(374,294.3)),('B',custom_function(374,294)),('C',custom_function(374,474))])
```

Basically, i want to iterate every element's `Total` in source `OrderedDict` and pick the other elements total and pass both of them as a parameter to the `customfunction` and get the value and store it. Also i need the `Name` to be same. How can i make this work, is there a smart way in python to achieve this.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing would be to iterate over list
`for od in list`

Assign
`name = od["name"]; total=...`

Create dict
`rd = OrderedDict(name=name)`
`result_list.append(rd)`

Iterate once again through list
`for od2 in list`

Check if they are the same
`if name != name2:`

Apply functions
`rd[name2] = f(tot, tot2)`

Comment: You are the only person to understand my question and provide a direction towards solution. Thanks Superior.